# Gedit can't save files

Tags: filesystem, gedit

Gedit can't save files.
My Gedit has greyed out the 'Save' button, and only offers to 'Close without saving'.
Other programs saves the same files without any problems and i seem to have enough rights. This happends with files all my home folder, even on a usb drive.
With 'gksudo gedit' it works. But i have the permission for the file, and i can save the file if i open it with Libre office write instead, only gedit will not.
If i make a test file on my desktop, that have the permission read and write, for Me, my group and others. I open it with gedit, i cannot save it. open it with libre office i can save it. with 'sudo gedit' it does not work, but with 'gksudo gedit' i can save it.
i must have broken something in gedit?

The only thing i have been messing with are changing the 'Run', 'Display or 'Ask' option for texts files in Nautilus, but i set it back.
I also reinstalled gedit.

I can't figure out what to do, please help.

Comment: Make sure the directory gedit wants to save a file is owned by you and not by root. You probably changed the default save location to something owned by root by using sudo or gksudo...

Comment: But, if i use 'LO Writer' in stead, i don't have any problems. And it, not only one directory, it everywhere, desktop, homefolder ext. drives. The problem are one with gedit.

Comment: Could you do a ` gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case gedit` and copy-paste the output to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide a link back here and then drop a comment @Fabby?

Comment: @Fabby I was installing ecryptfs-utils and did a lot in a SU terminal. Another user that tried to help me at the forums, thinks that i made problems in dbus. Unfortunately it's above my knowledge.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262774

Here are the pastebin of bith gedit and eog. All other apps and users work fine.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9912966/

Comment: Sorry, then I cannot help you.  If I were you, I'd reinstall and [start taking system backups](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) as you're definitely user type 4!  ;-(

Comment: @fabby, I was almost about to.
The weird thing is that it's the only user affected. Other user work perfectly.

Comment: I've got a solution for you then! :-)  (And sorry for not asking first: Do you have this in the guest session as well???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following steps to circumvent the issue: (this is a **workaround**, not a solution)

- create a new user (E.g. `mote2` for original user `mote`)
- with the same groups as the other user (if you need details on that, leave a comment)

Now:

1. open the file manager
2. browse to the `/home/mote` directory
3. **copy** (not move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/mote2/Downloads`
4. check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/mote/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
7. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser mote --remove-home`

## Done!

**Why?** As you have <strike>seriously messed up</strike> some problems with the current's user profile, some setting somewhere in one of the `.config` files is causing a problem.  As we can't solve this problem in a reasonable amount of time, it's best to just leave that profile behind and starting afresh!

Comment: Thanks, that was just the solution i had figured out my self. You get all the stars and upvotes i have. ;-)
Thanks

Comment: +1 This also works for problem files in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on my NTFS partition `/mnt/e` which is `E:\ ` within windows. I've been struggling for a couple of hours trying various things but `cp /mnt/e/bin/* /mnt/e/bin2/` was an easy fix!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yup: it's a universal solution independent of OS.